# Foreign key ID must be nullable, although I have CascadeOnDelete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two tables, which have a 1:n relationship. I used the following EF Code First relationship definition:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyPrimary>()
            .HasMany(x => x.MyOthers)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.primary_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Note that `primary_id` is a non-nullable column, that's also why I set the relationship to `.WithRequired()` - a MyOther needs to have a MyPrimary and cannot exist on its own.

Now I have the following code:

```
myPrimary.MyOthers.Clear();
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

And I receive the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Why? Shouldn't all the `MyOther` instances in `myPrimary.MyOthers` be cascade-deleted and therefore the non-nullable FK should not be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.Clear()` EF trying to unassign MyOther from MyPrimary, It is not smart enough to figure out that you want to delete MyOther records. Maybe after clear you will decide to add these MyOther records to another MyPrimary record. So you should to mark these records as deleted explicitly. You can write method similar to this

```
 public void MarkForDeleteItems<T>(ICollection<T> collection) where T : class
 {
     foreach (var collectionItem in collection.ToList())
     {
         ctx.Entry(collectionItem).State = EntityState.Deleted;
     }
 }
```

And then use it

```
MarkForDeleteItems(myPrimary.MyOthers);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Also `WillCascadeOnDelete` meaning that when you delete MyPrimary record than database will delete all MyOthers records which related to MyPrimary.

Comment: "Maybe after clear you will decide to add these MyOther records to another MyPrimary record." - thanks, that's the point I've been missing. Now everything is clear!